# How to change boot drive in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, boot

As shown in image , i want to change my boot drive. i want to choose 92 gb File system drive, please help how to change my booth drive from current drive to 92 gb drive, in that drive also have ubuntu , please help

[image]

```
sudo lspci -nn
```

[image]

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Basically, you have to install GRUB on that drive then change order of disks in BIOS settings.

Comment: if you had two os's installed the run boot-repair to show both the os's on startup.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it not shows at boot time, i repair my window, then on't knw how boot drive changed . Baisically when 1st time i install ubuntu then i install ubuntu in 2 drives, in which m currently working this drive is boot after repair.

Comment: you mean on the grub.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a program called Clonezilla.

Open Terminal

Type

Sudo apt-get install Clonezilla

Then type

sudo clonezilla

Choose your credentials and clone your drive over.